# Sending Multiple Gmail Attachments with Powershell

Tags: image, powershell, email, gmail, png

Title pretty much explains it. Right now from other sites I have gathered this:

```
$SendTo = "me@gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$EmailFrom = “me@gmail.com”
$EmailSubject = “Subject”
$Image = "0.png"
$Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image)
$att.ContentId = "att"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "password"); 
$body = '<img src="cid:att" />'
$Message.From = $EmailFrom
$Message.To.Add($SendTo)
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.Body = $body
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Message.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($Message)
$att.Dispose()
```

but it doesn't work, it gives me the error:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a 
secure connection or the client was not
authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. p56sm3035297qta.18 - gsmtp"
At A:\ScreenshotEmail.ps1:19 char:1
+ $smtp.Send($Message)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

I also want to send multiple pictures, "0.png" is the first, and I want to be able to add however many, like twenty, all in order like this:

> 0.png
>   1.png
>   2.png

And so on.

EDIT:
After adding LotPings' and MarliesV's code, this is what I have. It works, but it only sends 1.png, not both. I will have it send even more, but I'm only using two here for example.

```
$SendTo = "receiver@gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$EmailFrom = “me@gmail.com”
$EmailSubject = “Subject”
$Images = @()
$Images += "0.png"
$Images += "1.png"
foreach ($Image in $Images) {
    $Message.Attachments.Add($Image)
}
$Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($Image)
$att.ContentId = "att"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "password"); 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$body = '<img src="cid:att" />'
$Message.From = $EmailFrom
$Message.To.Add($SendTo)
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.Body = $body
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Message.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($Message)
$att.Dispose()
```

EDIT 2: Never mind, I got multiple to work. I feel like it is not as good as it could be, however. I think it would be more efficient to send everything that is contained in a folder instead, then put all of the pictures in a folder, so that there could be a theoretical infinite amount of attachments. Here's the code I have right now, tested working with 10 (actually 11, because 0-10 is 11) pictures, but did not appear in my inbox when I tried 20 pictures.

```
$SendTo = "RECIEVER@gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$EmailFrom = “ME@gmail.com”
$EmailSubject = “SUBJECT”
$Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -erroraction silentlyContinue
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer, 587)
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("ME@gmail.com", "PASSWORD"); 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$body = '<img src="cid:Images" />'
$Message.From = $EmailFrom
$Message.To.Add($SendTo)
$Message.Subject = $EmailSubject
$Message.Body = $body
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Images = @()
$Images += "0.png"
$Images += "1.png"
$Images += "2.png"
$Images += "3.png"
$Images += "4.png"
$Images += "5.png"
$Images += "6.png"
$Images += "7.png"
$Images += "8.png"
$Images += "9.png"
$Images += "10.png"

foreach ($Image in $Images) {
    $Message.Attachments.Add($Image)
}
$smtp.Send($Message)
$Images.Dispose()
```

EDIT 3:
Thanks to Swonkie we have this code which works wonders:

## Final Working Code

```
$message = @{
From = 'ME@gmail.com'
To = 'RECIEVER@gmail.com'
Subject = 'Subject'
Body = '<img src="cid:att" />'
BodyAsHtml = $true
Attachments = '0.png', '1.png', '2.png', '3.png','4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png', '8.png', '9.png', '10.png'
}

$server = @{
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('ME@gmail.com', (ConvertTo-    SecureString 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force))
    UseSsl = $true
}

Send-MailMessage @message @server
```

Be aware that Gmail seems to have an 11 attachment limit doing this.

Comment: Insert `$smtp.EnableSsl = $true`

Comment: Using `Send-MailMessage` is probably much more convenient. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage

Comment: @LotPings - Thanks, it works like a dream now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding multiple attachments is very easy with `Send-MailMessage`.

```
$message = @{
    From = 'me@gmail.com'
    To = 'receiver@gmail.com'
    Subject = 'Subject'
    Body = '<img src="cid:att" />'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Attachments = Get-ChildItem FolderWithAttachments
}

$server = @{
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('me@gmail.com', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force))
    UseSsl = $true
}

Send-MailMessage @message @server
```

By the way, because I use 2-factor authentication with my Google account, I had to create an app password for this to work. [This page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) explains why and how.

Comment: Gives the error 

`Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Dispose'.`

But it still works perfectly, thank you. Also, I think that Gmail limits to 11 attachments, because this way can't go over 11 either. Thank you!

Comment: Using 

`Attachments = Get-ChildItem .\`

seems to work, but I can't get 

`Attachments = Get-ChildItem .\folder`

to work, it still searches in the folder that the script is in. And I can't have that because then it tries to send the script itself as an attachment and Gmail blocks it.

Comment: @jangles my answer is a complete script in itself. Did you maybe add some parts from your original script like `$att.Dispose()`? Because I don't see where this dispose error should come from.

Comment: @jangles try to use an absolute path like `Get-ChildItem C:\Attachments`

Comment: I copied the code exactly and put in an absolute path like `A:\Folderwithscript\Folderwithpictures`, and it outputs: `Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 'A:\Folderwithscript\0.png'.` So it's not even looking in the right directory, it's looking in the script folder.

Comment: @jangles in my code there is no mention of `0.png`, but it appears in your error message. You seem to have a mess somewhere.

Comment: The 2FA part worked great for me. Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

To add multiple images you can just use the `$Message.Attachments.Add($att)` multiple times, but then with all the different images for `$att`. It would be easiest to do it in a loop.

```
$Images = @()
$Images += "0.png"
$Images += "1.png"
$Images += "2.png"
foreach ($Image in $Images) {
    $Message.Attachments.Add($Image)
}
```

Comment: I will add my current script to my orignal post after adding this code. It is only sending one picture, which is 1.png in this case.