# Send Powershell Email using Google 2FA?

Tags: .net, powershell, email, automation

I'm a Powershell developer, curious to what the community recommends for email providers for sending daily notifications.

This is for personal use, but I know Google's 2FA prevents automating this kind of thing.

Basically just want to be able to send myself a daily alert via email a la `Send-MailMessage`, any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail users can access their account on the official website or by using first-party or third-party apps and services instead. A first party app is for instance Google's official Gmail app for Android, while Thunderbird and the mail client app of Windows 8 are third-party apps.

Google [announced](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html) back in April 2014 that it would improve the sign-in security of its services and affect any application sending usernames and passwords to the company.

The company suggested to switch to OAuth 2.0 back then but did not enforce it up until now.

If you open the new [less secure](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) apps page under security settings on Google, you will notice that Google has disabled access by default.

Note: You see the page only if you are not using Google Apps or have enabled two-factor authentication for the account.

**You can flip the switch here to enable less secure applications again so that access is regained.**

[image]

Here an example to send email with SSL Authentification with an Hybrid code Batch and Powershell Script.

Just save it as ***Gmail_PS_Batch_Sender.bat***

```
<# : Batch portion
@rem # The previous line does nothing in Batch, but begins a multiline comment block
@rem # in PowerShell.  This allows a single script to be executed by both interpreters.
@echo off & Mode 100,5 & color 0A
Title Sending E-mail with SSL Authentification with an Hybrid code Batch and Powershell Script by Hackoo
echo(
rem # This a Powershell command executes the hybrid portion at the bottom of this script
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0}|out-string)"') do set "%%I"
exit /b
rem # End multi-line PowerShell comment block.  Begin PowerShell scripting.
: end Batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>
#################################### First 1 Step ###########################################
# First Step we encrypt the Plain Text Password to an encrypted one using the key AES.key
# Première étape, nous cryptons le mot de passe en clair vers un mot de passe chiffré
# à l'aide de la clé AES.key
$AppData = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')
$KeyFile = $AppData+"\AES.key"
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 32   # You can use 16, 24, or 32 for AES 
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | out-file $KeyFile
$AppData = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')
$PasswordFile = $AppData+"\Password.txt"
$Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$GmailUserName = Read-Host "Please enter your Gmail Account without ""@gmail.com"" "
$Password = Read-Host "Please enter your Gmail Password to be encrypted " -AsSecureString `
| ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile
#################################### First 1 Step ###########################################

#################################### Second 2 Step ##########################################
# We send the email with our encrypted Credentials
# Nous envoyons le courrier électronique avec les informations d'identification cryptés
#############################################################################################
Function Show-BalloonTip {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true)]
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Text,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Title,   
    [ValidateSet('None', 'Info', 'Warning', 'Error')]$Icon = 'Info',
    $Timeout = 10000
  )
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

  if ($script:balloon -eq $null) { $script:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon }

  $path                    = Get-Process -id $pid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
  $balloon.Icon            = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)
  $balloon.BalloonTipIcon  = $Icon
  $balloon.BalloonTipText  = $Text
  $balloon.BalloonTipTitle = $Title
  $balloon.Visible         = $true
  $balloon.ShowBalloonTip($Timeout)
  Start-Sleep -s 10
  $balloon.Dispose()
}
################################################################################################
function Show-Message {

param (
    [string]$Message = "Veuillez entrer votre message",
    [string]$Titre = "Titre de la fenêtre",
    [switch]$OKCancel,
    [switch]$AbortRetryIgnore,
    [switch]$YesNoCancel,
    [switch]$YesNo,
    [switch]$RetryCancel,
    [switch]$IconErreur,
    [switch]$IconQuestion,
    [switch]$IconAvertissement,
    [switch]$IconInformation
    )

# Affecter la valeur selon le type de boutons choisis
if ($OKCancel) { $Btn = 1 }
elseif ($AbortRetryIgnore) { $Btn = 2 }
elseif ($YesNoCancel) { $Btn = 3 }
elseif ($YesNo) { $Btn = 4 }
elseif ($RetryCancel) { $Btn = 5 }
else { $Btn = 0 }

# Affecter la valeur pour l'icone 
if ($IconErreur) {$Icon = 16 }
elseif ($IconQuestion) {$Icon = 32 }
elseif ($IconAvertissement) {$Icon = 48 }
elseif ($IconInformation) {$Icon = 64 }
else {$Icon = 0 }

# Charger la biblithèque d'objets graphiques Windows.Forms
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

# Afficher la boite de dialogue et renvoyer la valeur de retour (bouton appuyé)
$Reponse = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $Titre , $Btn, $Icon)
Return $Reponse
}
################################################################################################
$SuccessMsg = "The email was sent successfully ; Please, check your email !"
$FailureMsg = "ERROR occurred while sending the email"
$AppData = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('ApplicationData')
$PasswordFile = $AppData+"\Password.txt"
$keyFile = $AppData+"\AES.Key"
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$GmailEncryptedPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList($GmailUserName,$GmailEncryptedPassword)
$EmailFrom = $GmailUserName+"@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = $EmailFrom
$Subject = "Sending E-mail with SSL Authentification with an Hybrid code Batch and Powershell Script"
$Body = (Get-Date -format F)  + "  Hello ! the sending email is working now with PowerShell and Batch Script!"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer,587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = $Credentials
try
{
  $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
  Show-Message -Message $SuccessMsg -Titre $SuccessMsg -IconInformation
  Show-BalloonTip -Text $SuccessMsg -Title $SuccessMsg -Icon 'Info'
}
catch
{
  Show-Message -Message $_.Exception.Message -Titre $FailureMsg -IconErreur
  Show-BalloonTip -Text $_.Exception.Message -Title 'ERROR occurred while sending the email' -Icon 'Error' 
}
exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use gmail with enabled two factor authentication if you create an app password. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608644/2226112) and [Googles documentation here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).